# capybara acceptance test - how to select the right element from inspecting the UI

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara, ui-automation, capybara-webkit

In this crud test I create a log entry with @notes and will try to update the log by replacing @notes with @updated_notes.

```
@notes = Faker::Crypto.md5 
@updated_notes = Faker::Crypto.sha256
```

This block of code to create the log entry works. I used within and the id's of divs in the source code with inspect.

```
it 'User can update manpower log entry' do

# create a new entry
within '#manpower_log_div' do
  find('#manpower_log_notes').send_keys(@notes)
  click_button "+ Add"
  expect(page.has_css?('td', @notes)).to be true
end
```

Here I try to click the already existing notes on the page, which lets me edit them.

```
# click the already existing notes to be able to edit them
within '#manpower_log_div' do
  find('#inline_edit').click
end
```

The error received is

```
Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find css "#inline_edit"
```

Inspecting the element gives us this, but notice the id of the object is too specific: data-object_id="11747753". What element can I place in find that I can use every time I run this test?

```
<span textarea_cols="50" class="inline_textarea_edit inline_editable" data-object_field="notes" data-object_id="11747753" data-object_class="ManpowerLog" data-custom_callback="" id="ManpowerLog-11747753-notes" data-value_required="false">a5c3e556f108fd29b00150ca736c82d6</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the element by any valid CSS selector that would match it.  In your example you could use class or data attribute - or a combination of both.

```
find('span.inline_textarea_edit[data-object_field="notes"]').click()
```

Comment: That has been my understanding too but it doesn't always work. I tried your example and still received the same error: ElementNotFound.

Comment: If you're getting that error then that element is either not on the page, or is not visible on the page - output `page.html` to see what elements are actually there

Answer (score 0):

In your code `find('#inline_edit')` is looking for an element with id `inline_edit`. As [Thomas Walpole](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2709090/thomas-walpole) mentioned you can find your button using css selector for example by class:

```
find('.inline_textarea_edit')
```

or

```
find('.inline_editable')
```

or

```
find('.inline_textarea_edit.inline_editable')
```

Make sure that class is uniq for that element. If not, you'll need to use something else then class or something else together with class, you need to look for uniq attribute of that element.
Also make sure that your element is within element with ID `manpower_log_div` as you are using `within '#manpower_log_div'`

You can find more info about css selectors here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp